# Cosmos DB: Huge RU difference between C# and Data Explorer

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I run this query through both C# code and in Data Explorer

```sql
SELECT c._ts, c.id, c.sensors, c.meta, c.partition
FROM c 
WHERE c.partition IN ("1320","1321","1321")
  AND c.meta.created.ts >= 1597096800
  AND c.meta.created.ts <= 1648418399
  AND IS_DEFINED(c.sensors)
ORDER BY c.meta.created.ts DESC
```

## Request Charge in Data Explorer

19.7 RUs

## Request Charge from code

1334.5 RUs

This part is only run once. There is no loop

```cs
public async Task<CosmosDbResult> ListWithStreamAsync(string continuationToken = null)
{
    try
    {
        var result = new CosmosDbResult();
        double requestCharge = 0;

        var sqlQueryText = "SELECT c._ts, c.id, c.sensors, c.meta, c.partition FROM c  WHERE c.partition IN (\"1320\",\"1321\",\"1321\") AND c.meta.created.ts >= 1597096800 AND c.meta.created.ts <= 1648418399 AND IS_DEFINED(c.sensors) ORDER BY c.meta.created.ts DESC";
        var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
        using (var queryResultSetIterator =
            this.container.GetItemQueryIterator<Dictionary<string, object>>(queryDefinition, Base64Decode(continuationToken)))
        {
            if (queryResultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                result.RequestCharge = currentResultSet.RequestCharge;
                result.Data = currentResultSet;
            }
            log.AddNotice($"Listed items for partition {ids}. Operation consumed {requestCharge} RUs.", new object[] { ids, requestCharge });
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

How can it be such high difference with the same query? This just started to happen a couple of days ago like Microsoft have updated Cosmos DB as my backend haven't changed.

Kind regards Daniel

Comment: I'm pretty sure your portal-based query is only doing a single retrieval, vs multiple in your C# code. Have you counted how many times you're looping through more results? You haven't given any detail on that, or general query result size.

Comment: @DavidMakogon HasMoreResults is only called once but I think I need to look through some more examples from Microsoft as `await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync()` is the row that takes time to run.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `MaxItemCount = 100` to `GetItemQueryIterator` resulted in much better performance.

```cs
using (var queryResultSetIterator =
    this.container.GetItemQueryIterator<Dictionary<string, object>>(queryDefinition, Base64Decode(continuationToken), requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
    {
        MaxItemCount = 100
    }))
{
    if (queryResultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
        result.RequestCharge = currentResultSet.RequestCharge;
        if (oData.GroupBy == null && currentResultSet.ContinuationToken != null)
        {
            result.ContinuationToken = Base64Encode(currentResultSet.ContinuationToken);
        }
        result.Data = currentResultSet;
        result.Query = sqlQueryText;
    }
    log.AddNotice($"Listed items for partition {ids}. Operation consumed {requestCharge} RUs.", new object[] { ids, requestCharge });
    return result;
}
```